# Block comment inside function declaration?

Tags: c, enums, void

I'm going through this C code and the function declarations seem to contain block comments.  they look like this:

```
void show_rank (/*in*/ Rank rank);
```

is that actually a block comment in the arguments or does it have an alternate meaning?

The variable Rank is defined as

```
typedef enum
{
   Clubs, Spades, Diamonds, Hearts
} Suit;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just a comment. However, some other languages have declarations on parameters that show whether the intention of the parameter is for it to be an input to the function or the output from it (i.e. whether the function expects to read from it or write to it); in C, it is not available as a language feature, but some people might use comments of that sort to improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pure comment. Presumably, it is intended to annotate the purpose of the parameter (somewhat pointlessly since the parameter isn't a pointer so it can only be an input parameter).  No standard compiler interprets the comment.

You make the interesting claim:

> The variable Rank is defined as
>
> ```
> typedef enum
> {
>    Clubs, Spades, Diamonds, Hearts
> } Suit;
> ```

The name `Rank` in the declaration is a *type*, not a variable, and the enumeration you show is for suits, not ranks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be actually a block comment unless you use a special compiler/preprocessor/interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a normal comment with no effect on the code.